# Why is my batch file not running as expected?

Tags: batch-file

The code below is not running as I expected. The correct input portion `if %comp% ==` is running, but the wrong input portion `if /I NOT` is not running. When I put wrong input, it just closes, but I want it to start a reverse countdown from 5, shutting down the PC when the countdown reaches 0. I have `Rem`arked the problem causing portion.

```bash
@echo off
mode con: cols=1366 lines=768
TITLE Secur_AI winx64
echo This PC is password protected.
set comp=
set /p comp=Enter Password:

if /I "%comp%"=="Coachify" (
    echo Checking Password...
    timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
    @echo off
    color 02
    echo Password: Correct
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
    echo Establishing Firewall....
    timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
    echo Firewall: Established
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
    echo Establishing Secure Server Connection.....
    timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
    echo Secure Connection: Established
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
    msg * Welcome!
    timeout /t 02 /nobreak >NUL
)

if /I NOT "%comp%"=="Coachify" (
    echo Checking Password...
    timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
    @echo off
    color 04
    TITLE Self_Shutdown_Prompt
    echo Wrong Password.
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 100 >nul
    echo Intruder Detected.
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 100 >nul
    echo Initiating Protection Mode...
    timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
    echo Protection Mode Initiated.
    timeout /t 01 /nobreak >NUL
    set SecondsLeft=6
    call :LOOP %SecondsLeft%
    goto END

    :LOOP
    cls
    set /a SecondsLeft=%SecondsLeft%-1

    Rem Start of problem area.
    if %SecondsLeft% == 0 goto :eof
    call echo Initiating SelfShutdown in... %SecondsLeft% seconds.
    ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
    goto LOOP

    :END
    Rem End of problem area.

    shutdown -s -t 00
)
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When the command `if /I NOT "%comp%"=="Coachify" (...)` is read, everything within the parentheses is evaluated at that time. When a variable is both defined/modified, and used within those parentheses, you have to delay the pre-expansion of the variable, to prevent its value at read time, from being used.

Comment: No, I restructured your own question, and used `Rem`arks to highlight the problem area instead of your ill advised use of asterisks. If you want your code fixing quickly remove this line: ```if /I NOT "%comp%"=="Coachify" (```, then remove the last line, ```)```. Then just before the first ```)``` line, add the line: ```goto :eof```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how to mark the problematic area,(sign of a NOOB). BTW Thank you sooo... much. It work like a wonder. But please, can you explain how it fixed the problem by just removing the if /NOT statement? Isn't it necessary to define what should it do if the input is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested by @Compo worked.
Here's the re-corrected code:

```bash
@echo off
mode con: cols=1366 lines=768
TITLE Secur_AI winx64
echo This PC is password protected.
set comp=
set /p comp=Enter Password:

if /I "%comp%"=="Coachify" (
    echo Checking Password...
    timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
    @echo off
    color 02
    echo Password: Correct
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
    echo Establishing Firewall....
    timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
    echo Firewall: Established
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
    echo Establishing Secure Server Connection.....
    timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
    echo Secure Connection: Established
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500 >nul
    msg * Welcome!
    timeout /t 02 /nobreak >NUL
    goto :eof
)

echo Checking Password...
timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
@echo off
color 04
TITLE Self_Shutdown_Prompt
echo Wrong Password.
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 100 >nul
echo Intruder Detected.
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 100 >nul
echo Initiating Protection Mode...
timeout /t 03 /nobreak >NUL
echo Protection Mode Initiated.
timeout /t 01 /nobreak >NUL
set SecondsLeft=6
call :LOOP %SecondsLeft%
goto END

:LOOP
cls
set /a SecondsLeft=%SecondsLeft%-1

if %SecondsLeft% == 0 goto :eof
call echo Initiating SelfShutdown in... %SecondsLeft% seconds.
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul
goto LOOP

:END
shutdown -s -t 00
```

Comment: There should be avoided also the first command block by replacing `if /I "%comp%"=="Coachify" (` by `if /I not "%comp%" == "Coachify" goto WrongPassword` and replacing `)` by `:WrongPassword`. It would be good to insert after `set /p comp=Enter Password:` the additional command lines `if not defined comp goto WrongPassword` (user entered nothing) and `set "comp=%comp:"=%"` (remove all `"` from user input string). That would make the batch file code prompting the user for a string input fail-safe and secure.

Comment: I recommend further replacing `set /a SecondsLeft=%SecondsLeft%-1` by `set /a SecondsLeft-=1` which is the short form of *take value from variable* `SecondsLeft` *and subtract one and assign the result to variable* `SecondsLeft`. That syntax is explained by the help output on running `set /?` in a command prompt window. It would be also good to reference all executables with full path, i.e. `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe` instead of just `ping` and `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe` instead of just `timeout`. It is not clear why once __TIMEOUT__ is used for a delay and once __PING__.

Comment: `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 100 >nul` does not cause any delay other than the time required to start `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe` as the single __ICMP ECHO REQUEST__ is answered by the loopback adapter immediately with an __ICMP ECHO REPLY__. There is no wait with 100 ms wait time as that would require sending the __ICMP ECHO REQUEST__ to a device which does not exist or does not reply while a network exists and the device would be according to IP address theoretically reachable at all. The same is true for `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 500 >nul` which does not wait 500 ms.